# How to know the type of an element when looping through a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to come up with a generic function in Javascript that can loop through the form and clear any element of the form, based on its type.

In order to get this done, I wanted to know dynamically what kind of form element I'm dealing with, including, but not only, selects, input texts, text areas, input buttons....

So, how can I differentiate between these elements, so I can deal with each type in a proper way?

Comment: Some evidence at an attempt would be nice, what code have you got so far? What have you tried?

Comment: to clear you don't need to be as precise as knowing the type of every element, you could just write one rule for each type, e.g. `$('form input[type="text"]').val('');` `$('form select).val('');` `$('form input[type="checkbox"]).prop('checked', false);`

Comment: Isn't that what a [reset](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#reset-button-state-(type=reset)) button does? No script required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `type` property, which is defined for controls according to [HTML5 CR](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) and in browser practice, even for controls that cannot have `type` as HTML attribute. For example, for a `select` element, the value of the property is `select-one` if the `multiple` attribute is absent, and the string `select-multiple` otherwise.

So if you traverse all descendants of a `form` element, you’ll recognize controls (form fields) from the `type` property; for other elements, `type` is usually undefined.

Comment: I don't see *type* specified for the [textarea element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/forms.html#the-textarea-element). Form controls are easily found using [form.elements](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-form-elements).

Comment: @RobG, it’s under “DOM Interface”. The `elements` property can be useful for traversal, but it has some oddities, e.g. it does not contain image buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you started

```
$('form :input').each(function(i, el){
    var type = el.tagName;
});
```

The `:input` selector basically selects all form controls.

Without jQuery:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('theform').elements;
for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
{
    console.log(elem[i].type);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ga7q/2/

Comment: OP never mentions the use of jQuery

Comment: `The :input selector basically selects all form controls.`— no, it doesn't. Why `el.tagName` in one part and `el.type` in another? Not all form controls have a type.

Comment: @RobG Yes, it does. It's quoted from the API btw. I just wanted to show him a couple of useful properties.

Comment: Cool, [`:input is a jQuery extension`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/). Wonder if they considered a more obvious `:control` selector. Or since it's peculiar to jQuery, `:j-control`.

Comment: @RobG Yea, they need to work on the naming. No other jQuery selectors are prefixed with `j-`, though. I would prefer something like `:formelement`.

Comment: It makes it clear it's specific to jQuery and prevents clashes with possible future W3C selectors, *cf* vendor specific property prefixes like `-moz-`, `-o-`, `-webkit-`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider use a `reset` button.
Like this.

```
<form action="">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="email">
    <input type="number">
    <input type="radio">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <select>
        <option value="">None</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="reset">
</form>
```

It's clean, fast, compatible with IE 2 and native.

[MDN Compatibility Table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#compat-desktop)

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZQ3v/1/)

**[EDIT]**
And if you need to trigger the reset by code you can use `formElement.reset()` that is the same. Here is the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset)

Comment: The reset button is great, but it does not work for me because what I need is a function to be called from another function to clean the form values. It's not an user triggered event.

Comment: You should read the MDN Reference link that I posted. You can use trigger reset by javascript using `myForm.reset()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tagName. With jquery you can use the following code

```
$('form').children().each(function()
{
 var elementType=$(this).prop('tagName');
});
```

With simple Javascript `element.tagName` will work.

Comment: You're iterating forms, not elements.

Comment: I think he wants to know what form elements are present inside the form? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, and that's not what you're getting here. `this` is a `<form>`

Comment: `$(this).prop('tagName')` is a lot more to type than `this.tagName`. A form can have many children that aren't controls (input, select, textarea, etc.).